# Separate bibliographies for each chapter

Tags: chapters, natbib

I'm in the process of writing a document with several chapters.
So I have a main folder, where I have main.tex and then I have subfolders `/Chapter1` and `/Chapter2` for `Chapter1.tex` `chap1.bib` and `Chapter2.tex` `chap2.tex` respectively.

My a sample of my `main.tex` looks like this

```
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\begin{document}

\include{Chapter1/chapter1}
\include{Chapter2/chapter2}

\end{document}
```

`Chapter1.tex` and `Chapter2.tex` looks like as follows
         ========================================================================

```
\chapter{Title of the First Chapter}  %


\graphicspath{{Chapter1/Figs/}}

textafsdsafadfadfadfadfadfa (body)

\bibliography{chap1} 

\pagebreak

========================================================================
\chapter{Title of the Second Chapter}  %


\graphicspath{{Chapter2/Figs/}}

textafsdsafadfadfadfadfadfa (body)

\bibliography{chap2} 

\pagebreak
```

=========================================================================

Could you please let me know how to achieve my goal? I would really appreciate this..

Thank you

Cha

Comment: Please do not post such fragments only. Most likely you meant `chap2.bib` instead of `chap2.tex`

Comment: Is this really natbib specific, or can it be achieved with refsection? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87414/per-chapter-bibliographies-in-biblatex

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300144/

Comment: Perhaps the `chapterbib` package is useful. There's quite a lot of relevant questions on this site, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292499/chapterbib-gives-citation-undefined-and-all